# Missing tags after SVN to Git conversion

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I'm trying to convert a Subversion repository to a Git repository using the following commands.:

```
git svn clone URL_TO_SVN/PROJECT --authors-file=users.txt -T trunk -b branches -t tags/release
```

The only thing that differs from the SVN standard layout is that the SVN tags stored under `tags/release`.

After moving the [SVN tags to be proper Git](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) tags:

```
cp -Rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/tags/release/* .git/refs/tags/
rm -Rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/tags
```

I only get a few tags, but not all SVN tags are now Git tags.

In the SVN repo are tags from version 0.1 up to 0.35.2, but in the Git repo I only have the tags 0.33.10, 0.34.0, 0.34.1, 0.34.2, 0.35.0, 0.35.1, 0.35.2.

How can I convert all SVN tags to Git tags?

Answer (score 1):

I've copied the code from the Net, but the original URL is no longer valid. Here is the code:

```
# Convert branches and tags

git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/svn |
   sed 's#svn/##' | grep -v '^tags' |
      while read aBranch; do git branch $aBranch svn/$aBranch || exit 1; done

git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/svn/tags/ |
while read tag; do
    GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="`git log -1 --pretty=format:\"%ad\" \"$tag\"`" \
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="`git log -1 --pretty=format:\"%ce\" \"$tag\"`" \
    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="`git log -1 --pretty=format:\"%cn\" \"$tag\"`" \
    git tag -a -m "`git for-each-ref --format=\"%(contents)\" \"$tag\"`" \
        "`echo \"$tag\" | sed 's#svn/tags/##'`" "$tag" || exit 1
done
```

It is a part of my [git2svn](http://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=tree;f=svn;hb=HEAD) script.

Comment: Could you please explain, what the above code snippet does?

Comment: Branches: it runs through references in `refs/remotes/svn` and create branches for every reference found. Tags are a bit more complex: for every reference in `refs/remotes/svn/tags/` the code restores `GIT_COMMITTER_*` info and creates a new tag using that info.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that your repo was packed and thus some references were in pack files already and thus you cannot simply use `cp` or `rm` on them.

But anyways, for a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)